# Installation of GDAL 1.10 in Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gdal

Is there an easy way to install GDAL/OGR 1.10 in Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 12.04 on a Windows 8 Machine using virtualbox. GDAL/OGR installed  http://gdal.gloobe.org/python/introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, I have tried it in Windows 7 and works great:
[GIS Internals Development Kits](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php)